# With WPF/MVVM detect textbox change on save

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Using WPF & MVVM with entity data model, I am trying to detect when any one of my six textboxes have changed when clicking the save button.  I want to save all changes which work fine, but I also am updating a grid elsewhere in the view, only if one of those textboxes have changed.

I am new to wpf and not sure what approach to take.  Do I use something like UpdateSourceTrigger in the propery of the textbox in the xaml or use validation...or something  else?  And whatever the best way, could you please explain how/why?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be if you had a different variable for each TextBox in your ViewModel and use TwoWay binding. And implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface too, which allows your ViewModel to notify the View that a property value has changed. I hope this steers you in the right direction and helps you solve your problem.

Other way would it be to use a flag to show that a value has changed and your Save would take a look at this flag and take the right action. You could set the flag in the properties Setter.

Answer (score 1):

**BigL** gave excellent hint - thanks.

May I add:
In the XAML of your WPF-Window, you would have the following for your TextBox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyPath, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

and it's the ....

> UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

... at the end of the tag, that does all the miracle (as **BigL** mentioned above). Maybe that's what you were looking for, because it detects the text-change in your Textbox independently whether it has focus, lost focus, never got focus at all, etc ....
Hence, I think that should do the trick for you :-)

works fine for me ....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on the problem: you want to detect IF something has changed WHEN you push the Save button?  If so, why?  Why not check it BEFORE allowing the Button to be pressed?  I'm not trying to be obtuse, I'm trying to drive to the intent.

Most likely, you will want to use TwoWay DataBinding on each of the text boxes back to properties in the VM.  The Grid can also bind to these properties and the updates will happen automatically, and only when something changes.  You can also create private OriginalValue properties to easily compare if the values have changed.

Further, I would bind the Save Button to an ICommand (I prefer a RelayCommand). This will allow you to control the Enabled state of bound buttons from the ViewModel by analyzing the change state of the properties.